# [here-api]How can I create a route without knowing the destination?

Tags: here-api

I want to implement the Here functionality "Implementing Search along the route" but without knowing the destinations I cannot create a route and then I cannot use this function.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Mats

Read the documentation

Answer (score 0):

The destination parameter is required in the HERE APIs to calculate the route.

//Pankaj